# How to pass a constant to a ConnectableObservable in RX js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, rxjs

I am trying to implement google map using RX js and google map api, I have to set the marker and same information I have to show in the Html file(coordination information and title I have sent).Here is the code snippet I have implemented :

**Code from TS file:**

```
import * as GoogleTypes from '../../../src/aem-components/google-maps';
markers$: ConnectableObservable<GoogleTypes.Marker[]>;
export class GoogleMapMarkersDemoComponent implements OnInit {
  markers$: ConnectableObservable<GoogleTypes.Marker[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
    const markrs: GoogleTypes.MarkerData[] = [
      {
        location: { latitude: 38.9170822, longitude: -94.6587262},
        options: {
          label: 'Store A',
          position: {lat: 38.9170822, lng: -94.6587262}
        }
      }
    ];
}
```

and same I have to pass that observale in the HTML file.

**Html File code:**

```
<dl
     *ngFor="let marker of markers$ | async"
     class="py-10 list-details marker">
     <dt class="row between-xs mx-0">
       <span class="mr-10 text-uppercase text-truncate">Label 1</span>
     </dt>
     <dd>
       Coordinates
       <code class="bgc--white">
       ({{marker.getLocation().latitude}}˚, {{pin.getLocation().longitude}}˚)
       </code>
     </dd>
</dl>
```

I have to pass this constant variable into the observable, new to Rx js and search on google not finding any solution.

Please suggest me how can I do that or any new approach with I can implement.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
ngOnInit() {
const markrs: GoogleTypes.MarkerData[] = [
  {
    location: { latitude: 38.9170822, longitude: -94.6587262},
    options: {
      label: 'Store A',
      position: {lat: 38.9170822, lng: -94.6587262}
    }
  }
];
this.markers$=Observable.from(markrs)
}
```

Comment: Getting the error : Type 'Observable<MarkerData>' is not assignable to type 'ConnectableObservable<Marker[]>'.
  Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable<T>' is not a class derived from 'ConnectableObservable<T>'.

Comment: change   markers$: ConnectableObservable<GoogleTypes.Marker[]>;
 to   markers$: Observable<GoogleTypes.Marker[]>;

Comment: Still getting the error: Type 'Observable<MarkerData>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Marker[]>'.
  Type 'MarkerData' is not assignable to type 'Marker[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'MarkerData'.

Comment: I would use type any to begin with Observable<any> and markrs:any[]